# How do I make a same range

Tags: highcharts

I have the range of data from 1 to 200 for my charts.

I want to make fixed range:

```
tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
    return [1,10,20,30,200];
}
```

but range from 30 to 200 more than the other ranges. [CHART](http://jsfiddle.net/elias2012/b5Kkk/6/)

I want to look each color range with same height?
[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us some more details, what u want with 30 to 200 to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not possible you want to show representation of data, data of `[ 20 - 30 ]` can not be equal to `[ 30 - 200 ]`. so it always be different in height.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you need to manipulate the `X` & `Y` values in the `Plotbands`.

```
plotBands: [{ 
                     color: 'rgba(1, 143, 189, 1)',
                     from: 0,
                     to: 50
                 },
```

Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b5Kkk/7/) is what u needed.

For multiple plot bands with ***irregular intervals*** it is not possible to achieve equal area of color ranges.

Comment: no, I want to save this range: `color: 'rgba(1, 143, 189, 1)',
                         from: -2,
                         to: 10
                     },
                       { 
                         color: 'rgba(157, 200, 5, 1)',
                         from: 10,
                         to: 20
                    },
                       { 
                         color: 'rgba(202, 1, 94, 1)',
                         from: 20,
                         to: 30`

Comment: -2 to 10 - this color rgba(1, 143, 189, 1)
10 to 20 - this color rgba(157, 200, 5, 1)
20 to 30 - this color rgba(202, 1, 94, 1)
and 30 to 200 - this color rgba(232, 204, 0, 1)
and I want equal ranges

Comment: Check the API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands. The from and to positions draw bands in terms of axis units. When you specify a greater interval, plot band consumes a greater region of the  chart. You need to equally distribute the range among the plot bands in order to achieve equal "regions".

Comment: I ask, can be done so as not to take a large portion of the graph if the range is larger than the others

Comment: How do I make equal range from 30 to 200 and ranges from -2 to 10, from 10 to 20 ???